# Projectile motion. Is there a point where sum of the forces is 0?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

Body of mass **m**, is thrown with initial speed, at an angle **α** from a horizon. Neglecting wind resistance, is there a point on the trajectory where the sum of forces is **0**?

I don't think so, but maybe at the highest point?

Comment: At the highest point the velocity is zero. But to look for forces velocity is not interesting, acceleration is. And the acceleration at the highest point is *not* zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you always have a constant downward force (gravity) of $-mg$. One can argue that once the projectile has landed on the earth, the forces sum up to $0$ but I do not think the question aims at that.